# Cannot call RICHTEXT.RichtextCtrl from SQL Server 2008 (on Windows 2008 Server x64)

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, activex, richtextbox, 64-bit

I want to use the fallowing function in my SQL-Server:

```
CREATE FUNCTION RTF2TXT(@in varchar(8000)) RETURNS  varchar(8000) AS 
BEGIN

DECLARE @object int
DECLARE @hr int
DECLARE @out varchar(8000)

-- Create an object that points to the SQL Server
EXEC @hr = sp_OACreate 'RICHTEXT.RichtextCtrl', @object OUT
EXEC @hr = sp_OASetProperty @object, 'TextRTF', @in
EXEC @hr = sp_OAGetProperty @object, 'Text', @out OUT
EXEC @hr = sp_OADestroy @object
RETURN @out

END
GO
```

The Problem is, that I always get NULL from the function. It cannot create the RICHTEXT.RichtextCtrl-Object. I think, the problem is, that this is a x64 Server. Does someone have an Idea how I can solve this?

I have already done successfully:

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO
sp_configure 'Ole Automation Procedures', 1
GO
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE
GO
```

to enable OLE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have previously done similar things using CLR stored procedures. Is this an option for you?

Comment: I have also tested this way. But I need several additional assemblies registered in sql-server. How do you do this?

Comment: Via the `CREATE ASSEMBLY` syntax - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189524.aspx

Comment: And which Assembly do you need? - Only System.Windows.Forms?