# SQL Strip the Font Format(Colour or other)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a problem to strip out the format in a note table
Here is an example:

```
";\red31\green73\blue125;
\viewkind4\uc1\ltrpar\f0\fs20 USEFUL TEXT BODY \cf1\f3 
\ltrpar\f0\fs17 
"
```

How to get rid of those stuff? I want to play safe not to replace anything after'\'

Many thanks,
Rick

Comment: What part is the font format? Everything that is not USEFUL TEXT BODY ?

Comment: You could try to follow a long path starting here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11948461/cannot-call-richtext-richtextctrl-from-sql-server-2008-on-windows-2008-server-x

Answer (score 0):

Your making it quite difficult for yourself by not replace '\' .
If you look at http://other9.tripod.com/Refs/easy-rtf.html you will see that there are different RTF codes and there is no default size for the codes.

Additionally, it is not like HTML where there must be a necessary "closing" tag which makes it additionally difficult.

The only thing I can think of is to record all possible RTF codes (or use an RTF parser library) and hence be able to recognize if a \ is or is not RTF code.

Comment: Thanks Meewok. Actually that was in RTF format. I used a function that I found here:  http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=90034

Comment: But it doesn't work perfectly as you can see there are still some formatting code left over. I am wondering if there is a perfect function that can strip or convert the RTF code. Thanks